# How can I extend this clothes washer drain pipe to reach the sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, washing-machine

Installing a new washer, I found the drain hose is too short to reach the sink it will drain into. The old washer had the drain hose coming out of the right side of the appliance but this one has the hose coming out of the left side.

There is a standpipe in the ground in front of the washer, but it has much too little vertical drop to be used for the washer. So, I need to get the washer draining into the sink as the last one did.

How can I extend the washer's drain hose without it leaking? Turning the water on only during a wash will help avoid any bad leaks, and beneath the drain hose is just concrete in a utility room that is very dry most of the time (low humidity, moisture seeps into floors only during big snowmelts) so some leaking is not catastrophic - still I'd rather set this up so it works properly by design.

The major challenge I see is the washer drain hose being horizontal when I extend it fully. Horizontal pipe couplings seem more prone to leak to my non-expert intuition. If I coupled the washer's hose with an extension vertically, it would add a significant amount of turns and length to the overall drain hose.

Here's the setup:

Washer and sink. Washer's drain hose starts on far end of washer.
[image: washer and sink]

Here's the far end of the washer, where its drain hose starts.
[image: washer]

Here's a close up of the drain hose reaching toward the sink.
[image: close up drain hose]

Another close up of the washer's drain hose. Note that it is semi soft, especially at the end of the hose.
[image: close up drain hose 2]

Can I just find a rubber hose that has a diameter large enough to contain the washer's hose, then insert the washer's hose ~1 inch into the larger diameter extension, and clamp them together using a hose clamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order an extra long washer drain hose.
Since your drain exits into a laundry sink there should not be concerns about flow restrictions. Be sure to secure the end in the sink as these washers push a lot of water very fast.
[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Long-Washing-Machine-Drain-Discharge/dp/B071G3HDL3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071G3HDL3)

Comment: Actually I already bought a very similar model. I was disappointed to find that it doesn't fit my washer's outlet, even though it says "Formed outlet end fits 1-Inch, 1-1/8-Inch, and 1-1/4-Inch stub outs on automatic washing machines." and my washer's outlet is about 1.2 inches max diameter.

Comment: Anyway, I guess you're confirming this is the correct way to go, and I just need to buy a larger diameter extension hose.

Comment: @cr0 the  end that attaches to machine should have graduated segments that can be trimmed off until you get to the correct size for your machine.

Comment: @cr0  this hose has three size options as you can see in the picture

Comment: I know there's three size options, but even the largest end did not fit over the original washer drain hose, it only fit _inside_ the washer drain hose which I figure is not a good connection. I didn't expect to remove the original washer drain hose, but rather connect an extension to it. You're saying (for this solution at least) to entirely replace the original drain hose?

Comment: @cr0 yes it is designed to replace the original not to extend it.