# Is it safe to extend the drain hose on my LG washer?

Tags: washing-machine

I just purchased an LG washer, model WM3900HWA. The drain hose is not long enough to reach the stand pipe. I have seen [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131095/how-can-i-extend-this-clothes-washer-drain-pipe-to-reach-the-sink) where the answer is to simply buy a longer drain hose. However, the user manual for this washer says the following:

> Do not install the drain hose with the end lower than 29.5 inches (0.7
> m) or higher than 96 inches (2.4 m) above the bottom of the washer or
> more than 60 inches (1.5 m) away from the washer.

How should I interpret the "60 inches away from the washer"? Is that just horizontal distance, or any combination of horizontal and vertical distance? The stand pipe is definitely closer than that, but I've never done anything with plumbing before so I want to make sure there isn't something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2):

I would not extend the drain hose that is supplied with the machine.

However, what I have done in the past is to put a stand pipe closer to the machine with a U trap to prevent the smells coming back up.

I did that with 2" pipe which solved the problem and never caused any back up for the machine.

The 60" is usually taken as horizontal distance but the man ual will make that clear.

Comment: All the manual says about the distance is what I wrote "more than 60 inches away from the washer". So I guess I'm left unsure... it sounds like that means I *can* extend the hose, but your first sentence indicates that this might be risky.

Comment: 60" is the horizontal distance measured from the drain of the washer to the discharge point, if it is too far, the water can backup causing problems. Suggest to install and extend PVC pipe from the stand pipe to a location close to the washer, and insert the drain hose to it. The PVC pipe shall be sloped down towards the stand pipe.

Comment: @r13 I suggested that in my answer, but I included a U trap so the smells don't come back up....

Comment: @SolarMike I've reservation on the U trap. IMO, the discharge velocity is helpful in forcing the escaping linen and small particles out/clear of the drain line. But I wouldn't reject it, if you feel it fits the bill :)